# Copy range from excel sheet to new one with name range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with a protected sheet which has predefined formats and formulas, and particular section of sheet has a drop-down with `Actual` and `Forecast` options.

When a user selects `Actual` in the drop-down, all the corresponding cells' formulas get converted to values (using `paste special`) and cannot be recalled. However, I need to revert this and recall all the formulas once the user has selected `Forecast` again on the sheet. This drop-down value is Column specific.

I am using below code to "paste special as values" and have the formulas in a Template sheet for copying back of the formulas.

The area I need help in is how to paste them in the destination cell

```
If ActiveCell.Value = "Actual" Then

    If Sheets("Template").Range("B1").Value <> 1 Then

        Answer = MsgBox("Once you change this drop down to 'Actual' the formulas below in the monthly breakdown section will be changed to constant values; and will not be revereted back", vbYesNo)

        If Answer = vbNo Then
            Application.Undo
            Application.StatusBar = ""
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
            Exit Sub
        End If

    End If

    Sheets("Template").Range("B1").Value = 1
    arrng = Cellinrng(ActiveCell)

    If InStr(1, arrng(0), "PrjRel") = 0 Then

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Exit Sub

    Else

        If ActiveCell.Row = Range("Rev_Line" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6))(-4, 0).Row Then

            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Dim activcell
            Set activcell = ActiveCell
            Call sbUnProtectSheet(ActiveSheet.Name)

            Range(Range("Rev_Line" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6))(-1, ActiveCell.Column - 2).Address & ":" & Range("Rev_Line" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6))(1, ActiveCell.Column - 2).Address).Copy
            Range(Range("Rev_Line" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6))(-1, ActiveCell.Column - 2).Address & ":" & Range("Rev_Line" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6))(1, ActiveCell.Column - 2).Address).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Range(Range("Rev_Line" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6))(5, ActiveCell.Column - 2).Address & ":" & Range("Rev_Line" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6))(5, ActiveCell.Column - 2).Address).Copy
            Range(Range("Rev_Line" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6))(5, ActiveCell.Column - 2).Address & ":" & Range("Rev_Line" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6))(5, ActiveCell.Column - 2).Address).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Range(Range("Rev_Line" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6))(8, ActiveCell.Column - 2).Address & ":" & Range("Rev_Line" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6))(8, ActiveCell.Column - 2).Address).Copy
            Range(Range("Rev_Line" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6))(8, ActiveCell.Column - 2).Address & ":" & Range("Rev_Line" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6))(8, ActiveCell.Column - 2).Address).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            Range(Range("Rev_Line" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6))(10, ActiveCell.Column - 2).Address & ":" & Range("Rev_Line" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6))(10, ActiveCell.Column - 2).Address).Copy
            Range(Range("Rev_Line" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6))(10, ActiveCell.Column - 2).Address & ":" & Range("Rev_Line" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6))(10, ActiveCell.Column - 2).Address).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            Range("Rev_Line" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6)).Select
            Range("Rev_Rec" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6)).Formula = "=SUMIF(OFFSET($C" & (ActiveCell.Row - 5) & ",0,0,ROW($C" & (ActiveCell.Row - 5) & ")-ROW($C" & (ActiveCell.Row - 5) & ")+1,COLUMN()-COLUMN($C" & (ActiveCell.Row - 5) & ")),""Actual"",Rev_Line" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6) & ")"
            Range("Rev_Rec" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6)).Copy
            Range("Rev_Rec" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False


            Range("Rev_Line" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6)).Select
            Range("Hours_Actual" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6)).Formula = "=SUMIF(OFFSET($D" & (ActiveCell.Row - 5) & ",0,0,ROW($D" & (ActiveCell.Row - 5) & ")-ROW($D" & (ActiveCell.Row - 5) & ")+1,COLUMN()-COLUMN($D" & (ActiveCell.Row - 5) & ")),""Actual"",sumRange)"
            Range("Hours_Actual" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6)).Copy
            Range("Hours_Actual" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            Range("Rev_Line" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6)).Select
            Range("Netwrk_Days_Actual" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6)).Formula = "=SUMIF(OFFSET($D" & (ActiveCell.Row - 5) & ",0,0,ROW($D" & (ActiveCell.Row - 5) & ")-ROW($D" & (ActiveCell.Row - 5) & ")+1,COLUMN()-COLUMN($D" & (ActiveCell.Row - 5) & ")),""Actual"",sumRange)"
            Range("Netwrk_Days_Actual" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6)).Copy
            Range("Netwrk_Days_Actual" & Right(arrng(0), Len(arrng(0)) - 6)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If

    End If

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are taking requires to many coding lines and will be hard to maintain if changes are required.

The solution I’m proposing uses the `Worksheet_Change` event to trigger the Procedures to Change the Formulas to values and to Restate the Formulas, it also uses the [Range.SpecialCells Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157(v=office.15).aspx) to identify the cells that need to be processed. This will ease the maintenance of your procedures in case of changes.

*This solutions assumes that:*

- The worksheet that users will change to Actual or Forecast is named
  `DATA` and the `DataValidation` is located at `D4` (change as
  required)
- The worksheet with the standard formulas is named
  `Template` (change as required)
- The worksheet `DATA` is a replica of
  the worksheet `Template` and both worksheets are protected (change as
  required)

**Solution:**

Copy this code in the VBA Module of the worksheet `DATA`

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Const kCll As String = "$D$4"
    With Target.Cells(1)
        If .Address = kCll Then Call WshAct_Actual_Or_Forecast(CStr(.Value2), .Worksheet)
    End With
End Sub
```

Copy this code in a Standard VBA Module

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WshAct_Actual_Or_Forecast(sCllVal As String, wshTrg As Worksheet)
Dim rTrg As Range

    Rem Application Settings Off
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Rem Set Target Range to Process
    Set rTrg = wshTrg.Range("E7:AB16")      'change as required
    ' In Procedures "Wsh_SetFormulas_ToValues" and "Wsh_SetFormulas_FromTemplate"
    '     the Target Range to Process is optional.
    '     Therefore if the Target Range is not provided the procedures
    '     will process the UsedRange of the Target Worksheet.

    Rem Validate Cell Value
    Select Case sCllVal
    Case "Actual"

        Rem Add here any required validation!


        Rem Message to User
        If MsgBox(Title:="Data Type [" & sCllVal & "]", _
            Prompt:="Formulas in the monthly breakdown will be changed to constant values" & _
                vbLf & vbLf & vbTab & "Do you want to continue?", _
            Buttons:=vbSystemModal + vbMsgBoxSetForeground + vbQuestion + vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then GoTo ExitTkn

        If rTrg Is Nothing Then
            Rem To change all formulas in target worksheet
            Call Wsh_SetFormulas_ToValues(wshTrg)
        Else
            Rem To change formulas only in Target Range
            Call Wsh_SetFormulas_ToValues(wshTrg, rTrg)
        End If

    Case "Forecast"
        Rem Add here any required validation!


        If rTrg Is Nothing Then
            Rem To restate all formulas in target worksheet
            Call Wsh_SetFormulas_FromTemplate(wshTrg)
        Else
            Rem To restate formulas only in Target Range
            Call Wsh_SetFormulas_FromTemplate(wshTrg, rTrg)
        End If

    End Select

ExitTkn:
    Rem Application Settings ON
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

End Sub


Sub Wsh_SetFormulas_ToValues(wshTrg As Worksheet, Optional ByVal rTrg As Range)
Dim rArea As Range
    Call Wsh_Protection_OFF(wshTrg) 'change as required

    Rem Validate\Set Target Range
    If rTrg Is Nothing Then Set rTrg = wshTrg.UsedRange

    Rem Set Target Range to Values
    For Each rArea In rTrg.Areas
        With rArea
            .Value = .Value2
    End With: Next

    Call Wsh_Protection_ON(wshTrg)  'change as required

End Sub


Sub Wsh_SetFormulas_FromTemplate(wshTrg As Worksheet, Optional ByVal rTrg As Range)
Const kWshSrc As String = "Template"
Dim wshSrc As Worksheet
Dim rSrc As Range, rSrcArea As Range, rTrgArea As Range

    Rem Set Source Worksheet - Template
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wshSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(kWshSrc)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wshSrc Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Template Worksheet is missing!", _
            vbSystemModal + vbCritical + vbMsgBoxSetForeground
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Call Wsh_Protection_OFF(wshSrc)
    Call Wsh_Protection_OFF(wshTrg)

    Rem Validate\Set Target Range
    If rTrg Is Nothing Then Set rTrg = wshTrg.UsedRange

    Rem Set Source Formula Range
    Set rSrc = wshSrc.Range(rTrg.Address).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, _
        xlErrors + xlLogical + xlNumbers + xlTextValues)

    Rem Set Target Range Formulas
    For Each rSrcArea In rSrc.Areas

        Set rTrgArea = wshTrg.Range(rSrcArea.Address)
        rSrcArea.Copy
        rTrgArea.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Next

    Call Wsh_Protection_ON(wshTrg)
    Call Wsh_Protection_ON(wshTrg)

End Sub
```

Suggest to read the following pages to gain a deeper understanding of the resources used:

[For Each...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264596.aspx), [Range Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx), [Select Case Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg278665.aspx),

[Worksheet Object Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff198331.aspx), [With Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264723.aspx).